# Why Debian APT is not listing the same upgrades on two different servers with the same APT config?

Tags: debian, apt

I have two dedicated servers (virtual machines), located in the same datacenter, both running latest Debian Bullseye.

Today, I ran `apt update` on the first one, and it listed several packages to upgrade, related to PHP update from 7.4.21 to 7.4.25.

Then I ran the exact same command on the other server, which listed nothing. And I checked, PHP was still running the previous version 7.4.21.

**Why the response of apt update is different on both servers?**
Not a big issue, I guess the upgrades will come to the other one as well at some point, but I'm curious.

PS: my `/etc/apt/sources.list` is the exact same on both machines:

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main contrib non-free

# Debian backports - to get packages from testing and unstable releases - see https://wiki.debian.org/Backports
# deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-backports main contrib non-free

# security updates, urgent ones
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free

# bullseye-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Do you have more lists in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`?

Comment: I do, only on the server that had its PHP upgrade. But the sources in the folder are about google drive package and owncloud, it has nothing to do with PHP, so it doesn't explain it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that both server are simply in the exact same state of level packages ?

Differences can come from deep packages dependancies (maybe a little tool is installed is one server and not the second one), or from a material difference (storage difference, processor, ...)

You can check the entire list of installed packages with `apt list`  in order to compare them !

Comment: I don't think both servers are in the exact same state of packages. Makes sense, that's probably why.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try clearing your apt cache, then pulling the lists again and checking for updates. It may just be a little dependency holding the update back.

To clean the apt cache, issue the following command: `sudo apt-get clean` 
To update the lists, issue the following command: `sudo apt-get update`

I hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks. Good hypothesis, tried it but didn't work though.

Comment: Can you try looking at which mirror server you are using? If you specify the US archive, it will I think round-robin balance it out across registered mirrors.

Comment: It's `ftp.fr.debian.org`. But I think it's related to a different state of packages, as pointed by @Martin